# Routing in Rails without controller in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I have a soccer related website and want to map the following URLs to the corresponding controller actions.

```
#         URL                   Controller Action
/:country/:competition_name => "competitions#index"
/teams/:country/:team_name => "teams#index"
```

You'll notice that the first URL does not have the controller name inside the URL. How do I match this URL to the corresponding controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
get '/:country/:competition_name/' => "competitions#index"
```

more info here: 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: I must be stupid because that is literally what I wrote myself and didn't try. Thank you!